# creating random objects using pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-physics

i am developing a game in python 3.3 using pygame.
can i please have a code which can do the following : 
create a screen of size say 800 * 800.
On the screen rectangles of a fixed size of 30*30 appear from the right and move slowly towards the left. as soon as they collide with the left wall, they disappear. the rectangles should come at random heights and fixed speed.
this is what i tried :

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
addrect = 0
addrect_rate = 40
rectangles = []
while True:
    for r in rectangles:
        addrect += 1
        if addrect == addrect_rate:
            addect = 0
            newrect = {'rect': pygame.Rect(40, 40, 10, 10),
                       'speed': rect_speed,
                       'image': pygame.draw.rect((50, 50), 10, 10)
                      } 
    for r in rectangles:
        rectangles.append(newrect)
```

The basic approach is this. please help me complete the code by drawing the screen, and making this work.
Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Now, in the edited question, i have included the sample of what i really want to do. help help help.

Comment: Technically speaking you are still asking us to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the code. I'm not experienced with pygame so I had to rewrite it to figure out how to get it done. I think I have put enough comments to make it clear what each part does.

If you want more training on how to use pygame, I used programarcadegame's "[introduction to sprites](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites)" to help me figure out how to get this done.

## Unladen European Box Swallows

```
import random

import pygame

# create a screen of size say 800 * 800.
screen_width, screen_height = 800, 800
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Unladen European Box Swallows')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

# On the screen rectangles of a fixed size of 30*30...
BLACK, WHITE = (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255)
swallows = pygame.sprite.Group()
class Swallow(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width=30, height=30, x=0, y=0, color=WHITE):
        #super(Swallow, self).__init__()  # this is for python 2.x users
        super().__init__()
        # self.image and self.rect required for sprite.Group.draw()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x_subpixel = x
        self.y_subpixel = y

    # subpixel required for constant movement rate per second
    @property
    def x_subpixel(self):
        return self._x_subpixel
    @x_subpixel.setter
    def x_subpixel(self, new_x):
        self._x_subpixel = new_x
        self.rect.x = int(round(new_x))
    @property
    def y_subpixel(self):
        return self._y_subpixel
    @y_subpixel.setter
    def y_subpixel(self, new_y):
        self._y_subpixel = new_y
        self.rect.y = int(round(new_y))


chance_to_appear = 0.01
airspeed_velocity = 100
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:
    ticks = clock.tick(60)
    # ...appear from the right [at random heights]...
    if random.random() < chance_to_appear:
        swallow = Swallow(x=screen_width, y=random.randrange(screen_height))
        swallows.add(swallow)
    # ...[and fixed speed]
    for swallow in swallows:
        swallow.x_subpixel -= float(airspeed_velocity) * ticks / 1000
    # as soon as they collide with the left wall, they disappear.
    for swallow in swallows:
        if swallow.x_subpixel <= 0:
            swallows.remove(swallow)
    # do regular pygame stuff
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    swallows.draw(screen)  # Group.draw uses each .image and .rect to draw
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

## Next Time

p.s. Please don't expect this much code creation for future answers on StackOverflow. I just wanted the experience of making this work. I hope it helps you. In the future, I recommend you read [this kind of guide](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on writing successful questions to get better answers and more votes.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things wetting with your code. First of all you should not add a rectangle to your list every go around, especially in a for loop.

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
addrect = 0 addrect_rate = 40
rectangles = []
while True: 
    addrect += 1
    if addrect == addrect_rate:
        # also wrong!!! You are using a pygame call in a dict newrect = {'rect': pygame.Rect(40, 40, 10, 10), 'speed': rect_speed, 'image': pygame.draw.rect((50, 50), 10, 10) }
        newrect = {'rect': pygame.Rect(40, random.randint(1,400), 10, 10), 'speed': rect_speed }
    for r in rectangles:
        r['rect'].x += r['speed']
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,0,0) r['rect'])
    #wrong
    #for r in rectangles: 
        #addrect += 1 
        #if addrect == addrect_rate:
            #addect = 0 
            #newrect = {'rect': pygame.Rect(40, 40, 10, 10), 'speed': rect_speed, 'image': pygame.draw.rect( }
    #for r in rectangles:
        #rectangles.append(newrect)
```